# What can I do to debug what is wrong with the postgresql url?

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I have a postgresql db in a react app using prisma

- DB name: newsletter
- User: postgres
- Password: foo$

I'm using the below env var (If you look closely I have escaped the $ sign in the password with a backslash)

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:foo\$@localhost:5432/newsletter"
```

When I run

```
npx prisma migrate dev
```

I get

```
Error: P1000: Authentication failed against database server at `localhost`, the provided database credentials for `postgres` are not valid.

Please make sure to provide valid database credentials for the database server at `localhost`.
```

I can see the db is running in pgAdmin
[image: dash1]
[image: dash2]

What can I do to debug what is wrong with the postgresql url?

Comment: URIs use percent encoding, not backslash escaping.

Comment: Tried both. DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:foo%$@localhost:5432/newsletter"
 doesnt work either

Comment: `%$` isn't the URL encoding for "$". `%25` is.

Comment: `$` doesn't have any special meaning in URLs, the escaping is for `.env` file. You shouldn't need it if you use single quotes.